# How can I mock a c# restful webservice and test it using java?

Tags: java, rest-api, mock

I suppose this is more like two questions.  Considering i wanted to do some automated testing of a restful web service that is written in c#.

- How can I using java and something like rest-assured test this API? can I some how mock it to test or do I need to write my automation code in c# in order to do this?
- Should I deploy the API on to a server e.g IIS and just run tests against the real service, How / when should we be mocking?

Thanks

Comment: You're testing the web service or the item that calls the webservice?

Comment: so say I had an API that the frontend was calling but I didn't want to test everything at the GUI layer for example, it may not interact with a third party system so to speak, but im thinking more generally for instances that it might as well, a holistic approach if you will would be ideal

Comment: Yeah so you wouldn't want to mock the API. You're testing the API itself so if you mocked it you would be testing the mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I using java and something like rest-assured test this API? can I some how mock it to test or do I need to write my automation code in c# in order to do this?

The same way you would with a Java application except it wouldn't be during deploy. The underlying language of the application shouldn't make a difference.

> Should I deploy the API on to a server e.g IIS and just run tests against the real service, How / when should we be mocking?

You should mock the API when you are testing the GUI bit not the API. This allows you to create controlled data for the GUI without relying on the API and verifies the GUI independent from the API.

Answer (score 0):

C# unittesting + TE (Test Author and Executing Framework) test harness from WDK are most powerful tools I have used.